# Find div in each divs and append it to div

Tags: jquery, html, find, append, each

I think this question is old, but i didnt finded any correct answer for me. For example i have tons of almost same divs:

```
<div class="grid-item">
    <img src="url to img" />
    <div class="city">London</div>
</div>

// etc...
```

Also, i have overlay content on top of image. I get it using jquery:

```
$('.grid-item img').wrap('<div class=\'overlay-wrap\'></div>');
$('.grid-item img').after('<div class=\'overlay\'></div>');
```

**The problem i have:**

```
$( ".grid-item").each(function() {
   $(this).find('.city').appendTo('.overlay');
});
```

This function does not work properly. This function appends to every `.overlay` in every `.grid-item`.

**Question:**

How to make it work? I need that every `.city` appends to its own `.overlay`.

Thank you for any answers. Sorry for bad english. **Merry christmas!**

Comment: Do you want to add a class ''overlay to the 'city'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just find the right overlay, you have the parent element, use it.

```
$( ".grid-item").each(function() {
   $(this).find('.city').appendTo($(this).find('.overlay'));
});
```